# "undefined reference to" NOT the template constructor,but the constructor of the class I'm trying to use the template with

Tags: c++, templates, codeblocks

It's difficult to search for anything on this problem because the wording is similar to the very common problem of template implementation.

My template works with integers, so that's not the problem here.

But when I try to use the template with another class that I've created, I get the error "undefined reference to 'MyNonTemplateClass::MyNonTemplateClass()'"

...and the line number referred to for that error is in the template class definition.

Is there something I need to do to use my template with my other class?

Comment: How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Sounds like it should be trivial to create one in your case.

Comment: Does that constructor exist?

Comment: It exists, and I've double checked includes and to make sure it's included in the project to be compiled.

Comment: The project has 12 files... I'm thinking about the best way to present the code...

Comment: I wouldn't claim that "double checking" means I'm right. I'll keep checking over and over again as long as you want me to.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find exactly what the problem was, but it was something in the project settings, not code.
I moved the code to a new project and the problem was gone.